# Enterpise Architect - is it possibhle to import SCXML file? How?

Tags: uml, enterprise-architect, scxml

Is it possible to import [SCXML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SCXML) file into Enterpise Architect as a "State Machine" or other diagram?

If so then how?

Answer (score 1):

Not out of the box. From what I saw it should not be too hard to write a script that reads XML and converts the tree to elements and connectors.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to not be possible directly in EA, but it does seem that a conversion script from XMI (what EA can export) to SCXML [exists](https://github.com/apache/commons-scxml/blob/master/extras/xmi2scxml.xsl).